# Python 3: .extend{}

Tags: python

As a novice I am trying to understand a particular part of len() .

```
friends = ["Alice", "Bob", "Carl", "John"]
print(len(friend))                         # answer = 4 (number of items in list)
friend.extend([1, 2, 3])  
print(len(friend))                         # answer = 7 (where does the "7" come from and what is it 
                                           # telling me?
```

Comment: list becomes `['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carl', 'John', 1, 2, 3]` so there is 7 elements

Comment: Is your question : what does list.extend do ? do `print(friend)` between each, you'll understand

Comment: just check what `len(list)` and `list.extend` function do, and the effect of each operation on the orignal list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Python's list methods append and extend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-list-methods-append-and-extend)

Answer (score 0):

When you call the extend method for a list with another list as an argument, you're basically combining both lists so all those elements, `1, 2, 3` are also stored in the list `friends` (by the way you have a typo, it should be `friends.extend()` not `friend.extend()`). So 4 elements + 3 elements gives you 7. It returns the length or how much elements the list has, which is 7 in this case since you added 3 more elements.